# Pull screen down to refresh data in qml

Tags: qml, click, buttonclick

On my Application I need to apply a feature like when I pull the screen down then the current page get refresh. For that I have done this

**Sample Code**

```
      Page {
height: 460
width: 300
id: app
property var refreshFlik: ""
Flickable {
    id:flick
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentHeight : rect.height
    Rectangle{
        id:rect
      color: "#fffff1"
        height: 540
        width: 300
    Text{
        id:text
       anchors.centerIn: parent
        text:"Hello World"
    }
    }
    onFlickStarted: {
         refreshFlik = atYBeginning
        busy.running=true
     }
    onFlickEnded: {
         if ( atYBeginning && refreshFlik )
         {
          //   updateDataFromServer();   // it's a function to update the data from server
             console.log("After getting the updated data refresh the page");
             // here after getting the data from server I need to refresh the whole page 
             busy.running=false
         }
     }
}
BusyIndicator{
        id:busy
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        running: false
    }
}
```

So This code is working fine, but one thing which i'm lacking at is not able to refresh the data on the screen. Suppose on Screen It shows "Hello world", but after I pull down the screen after getting the data from my server that text changes to something else according to the data i get from server.

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear. The same for the code you've provided. Please provide [mcve] and clarify the question.

Comment: To load into what? It's unclear from your question what are you talking about. What is `current page` in this context? So please review your question, post [mcve] and I think you will get an answer that solves the issue.

Comment: To understand how to "reload" your UI, we need to understand how it was initially loaded.

Comment: I have edited the whole question. Now it may be make more sense. I'm sorry for not giving details. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the whole thing I think its better you use a Component and loader as below

```
   Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")




    Component{
        id:toLoad
        Page {

            height: 460
            width: 300
            id: app
            signal reloadComponent()
            property var refreshFlik: ""

            Flickable {
                id:flick
                anchors.fill: parent
                contentHeight : rect.height
                Rectangle{
                    id:rect
                    color: "#55ff00ff"
                    height: 540
                    width: 300
                    Text{
                        id:text
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text:"Hello World"
                    }
                }
                onFlickStarted: {
                    refreshFlik = atYBeginning
                    busy.running=true
                }
                onFlickEnded: {
                    if ( atYBeginning && refreshFlik )
                    {
                        //   updateDataFromServer();   // it's a function to update the data from server
                        console.log("After getting the updated data refresh the page");
                        // here after getting the data from server I need to refresh the whole page
                        busy.running=false
                    }
                    reloadComponent()
                }
            }
            BusyIndicator{
                id:busy
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                running: false
            }


            Component.onCompleted:{
                console.log("loaded")
            }
        }

    }



    Loader{
        id:ldr
        sourceComponent: toLoad

        Connections{
            target:ldr.item
            onReloadComponent:{
                console.log("reloading")
                ldr.sourceComponent=undefined
                ldr.sourceComponent=toLoad
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: no it did't work. why you kept loader outside of the component

Comment: What is that you exactly trying to reload?is that the text or do you want to load the whole qml component?

Comment: whole component

Comment: To load the whole component you need the loader outside the component. Loader is the one who reload the component. That is why it is outside the component